# Log or Check When Disk Was Accessed

Tags: filesystems, logs, disk-usage, disk

Is there a way to log or check after the fact when a disk was accessed (either for read or write).  Ideally I'm hoping to check this for a whole disk (ie: /dev/sda), but if that's not possible I'll have to settle for checking each partition's file system (combination of ext4 and BTRFS) and assume nothing is accessing the partition table, RAID superblock, etc.

Comment: Do you mean the disk or a partition, volume group, or another filesystem? Is there a condition that you are looking for such as a certain process that is writing to it or reading from it?

Comment: Is this a primary OS disk?